# Possible to use a httpclient in bash script? For sessionbased HTTP GET and POST

Tags: bash, http, cookies, httpclient

I want to aoutomate logging in to a website and downloading a file.
Since it is session based and I have to send a token from inside the html with the login credentials as POST, I was wondering if there was a solution to this in bashscript?!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) may be the answer to your problem. It supports saving and loading cookies to / from a file.

The `--cookie-jar <file>` option causes curl to dump cookies to the given file after the request.

And the `--cookie <file>` option causes curl to load cookies from the given file before the request.

So you can use these options like this:

```
curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt http://www.example.com/
```

Posting can be done in many ways, but the --data-urlencode option is the easier:

```
curl --data-urlencode "username=john.doe" --data-urlencode "password=dummy" --cookie [...] http://www.example.com/
```